# number theory : let $a \in \mathbb Z^+$ find $(a,a+1)$

Tags: number-theory

let $a \in \mathbb Z^+$

find:

1)  $(a,a+1)$

2) $(a,a+2)$

please guide me to solve this question it's about number theory

Comment: does (a,a+1) stand for the gcd of a and a+1?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If you work a few examples I think you'll at least see what the answer to 1) has to be.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that
you are talking about
the greatest common divisor
(gcd).

For your problems,
all you need to know
is that
if d divides
 a and b,
then d 
divides a-b.

Apply this to your values.

Comment: There is a bit overlooked here for the second part. If $d$ divides $a$ and $a-2$ then all you can conclude is that $d$ divides $2$, which is not enough to complete the problem.

Comment: That's because there are two possible answers depending on the value of a.